# Kerio Mail Server on Leopard Client?

Tags: osx-leopard

What's the difference between running Kerio Mail Server on Leopard client vs running it on Leopard Server. If all I need is contact/calendar syncing among 4 macs and 4 iphones, is there a use of running it on Leopard Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference. So long as you have the OD extensions installed in your Leopard Server then your KMS install on Leoaprd client will be able to authenticate against your OD Server.

Comment: Not sure if I got this right. I can install KMS on a machine that "acts" like a server but has Leopard Client, as long as it has OD extensions?

Comment: KMS can be installed on any machine. Mac OS X client, server, Linux, doesn't matter. So long as your Open Directory Server has the KMS OD extensions installed. Or else the KMS will not be able to authenticate against OD

Answer (score 1):

You only need the OD extensions if you're authenticating your Kerio users via Open Directory on Mac OS X Server. If you authenticate via Kerio's built-in LDAP you can install Kerio on either OS and it will work fine.

We use OS X 10.6 client and all users (92) authenticate via the built-in Kerio LDAP server.